# Can't install SPECjvm2008

Tags: jvm, java

Specification:

OS: RHEL6 x86_64

JRE: jre-6u30-linux-x64-rpm.bin - downloaded from oracle java website

SPECJVM2008: downloaded from http://www.spec.org/jvm2008/

---

To install SPECJVM2008, I run this command:

```
java -jar SPECjvm2008_1_01_setup.jar
```

but nothing happens after that, the command line just hangs.

I tried `java -verbose -jar SPECjvm2008_1_01_setup.jar`, and found out that it stops at:

```
....
[Loaded com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.InstallUninstaller from file:/root/specjvm/SPECjvm2008_1_01_setup.jar]
[Loaded ZeroGbq from file:/root/specjvm/SPECjvm2008_1_01_setup.jar]
[Loaded ZeroGd3 from file:/root/specjvm/SPECjvm2008_1_01_setup.jar]
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use the -i console option to install it command line:

```
$ java -jar SPECjvm2008_1_01_setup.jar -i console
```

In case you prefer a graphical installer:

Since you probably don't want to install a X server on your server just for this install process you can:

- [Install Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) on your windows client and start it (Xming will show up as a notification icon on the taskbar)
- Allow X forwarding on the ssh daemon on your server. Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and make set "X11Forwarding yes"
- Enable X11 forwarding in your putty client;

  - Check the "Enable X11 forwarding" checkbox at Connection => SSH => X11
  - Set "X display location" to localhost:0
- Login on your server using those settings with putty.
- Now start the SPECjvm2008 install (java -jar SPECjvm2008_1_01_setup.jar)

The graphical installer will now popup on your windows client.

(There are some prerequisites which I didn't describe here. You will find more information on the Xming website.)